# Mozilla returning error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: php

I hava a function in php that returns JSON data to the API call.

Function is

```
public static function renderJSON($data, $httpResponseCode = 200) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        http_response_code($httpResponseCode);
        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

And when I try to access the URI for the API request I get a JSON response, but also an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

When I look at raw data, it seems like a normal JSON array.

```
[{"id":"7","name":"Harry Potter","author":"J.K. Rowling","price":"50","uri":"http:\/\/localhost\/netbeans\/EP_project\/api\/book7"}]
```

I can't find the reason for the error, since the first column of the first row is `[` which is a valid character in JSON.

Comment: yes, json is ok ... but , what does the browser receive ?  console.log it and see for yourself.  Typically this error is caused by the fact that the browser is getting some `php wine` in a html form.

Comment: This is what the browser gets. I `var_dump()`-ed it since it's php not js. 
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/home/user/NetBeansProjects/EP_project/controller/ShopRESTController.php:26:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Harry Potter&quot;,&quot;author&quot;:&quot;J.K. Rowling&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:&quot;50&quot;,&quot;uri&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/netbeans\/EP_project\/api\/book7&quot;}]'</font> <i>(length=142)</i>
</pre>

Comment: You need to console.log the response in the browser so that you can be able to clearly see what the response is.

Comment: Stupid question, i guess....but how do i console log in php?